# Avoid indentation of new paragraph with sloppypar

Tags: formatting, indentation, inline

I would normally write an equation followed by some text like this:

```
  \begin{equation}
     2+1
  \end{equation}
  where...
```

In which case the where clause is NOT indented.

Now, I need to use sloppypar in the paragraph with the where clause because the inline math formulas will run into the margin otherwise, like this:

```
  \begin{equation}
    2+1
  \end{equation}
  \begin{sloppypar}
    where...
    \end{sloppypar}
```

The problem is that when I do it, the paragraph gets indented, like a new paragraph.  How to avoid it?

Comment: in addition to the suggestions made in the answers, you could also just begin the `sloppypar` with the beginning of the paragraph above the display.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The environment `sloppypar` is basically defined as

```
\newenvironment{sloppypar}{\par\sloppy}{\par}
```

Just define a new environment that omits the initial `\par` to be used in this and similar cases (that is, after math displays).

```
\documentclass[draft]{article}

\newenvironment{sloppypar*}
 {\sloppy\ignorespaces}
 {\par}

\begin{document}

Some normal paragraph, with text running smooth for justification.
Some normal paragraph, with text running smooth for justification.
Some normal paragraph, with text running smooth for justification.
Some normal paragraph, with text running smooth for justification.
\begin{equation}
    2+1
\end{equation}
\begin{sloppypar*}
here many long formulas $aaaaaaaa$ $bbbbbbbb$ $ccccccccccccc$ $dddddddddddddd$
here many long formulas $aaaaaaaa$ $bbbbbbbb$ $ccccccccccccc$ $dddddddddddddd$
here many long formulas $aaaaaaaa$ $bbbbbbbb$ $ccccccccccccc$ $dddddddddddddd$
here many long formulas $aaaaaaaa$ $bbbbbbbb$ $ccccccccccccc$ $dddddddddddddd$
here many long formulas $aaaaaaaa$ $bbbbbbbb$ $ccccccccccccc$ $dddddddddddddd$
\end{sloppypar*}

Some normal paragraph, with text running smooth for justification.
Some normal paragraph, with text running smooth for justification.
Some normal paragraph, with text running smooth for justification.
Some normal paragraph, with text running smooth for justification.
\begin{equation}
    2+1
\end{equation}
here many long formulas $aaaaaaaa$ $bbbbbbbb$ $ccccccccccccc$ $dddddddddddddd$
here many long formulas $aaaaaaaa$ $bbbbbbbb$ $ccccccccccccc$ $dddddddddddddd$
here many long formulas $aaaaaaaa$ $bbbbbbbb$ $ccccccccccccc$ $dddddddddddddd$
here many long formulas $aaaaaaaa$ $bbbbbbbb$ $ccccccccccccc$ $dddddddddddddd$
here many long formulas $aaaaaaaa$ $bbbbbbbb$ $ccccccccccccc$ $dddddddddddddd$

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

It's not elegant, but adding  \noindent after \begin{sloppypar} solves the problem!