# Is possible to break a line automatically?

Tags: math-mode, formatting, line-breaking

Writing a latex document it is possible that a math-text is putted into two different lines but obviously this could be unpleasant so that I thought to confront with this using the following solution.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amssymb}

\begin{document}
    \noindent
    This is an example of unbroken line.

    %\vspace{0.1cm}
    
    \noindent
    By the equation above we argue that the following equation (by Euler) $e^{i\pi}+1=0$ which is useful.

    \vspace{1cm}

    \noindent
    This is an example of \textbf{manually} broken line

    %\vspace{0.1cm}
    
    \noindent
    By the equation above we argue that the following equation (by Euler) 
    \linebreak
    $e^{i\pi}+1=0$ which is useful.
\end{document}
```

However I dislike it since it is not just automatic so that if I modify the text then I have to remember I inserted the command \linebreak which shall delete after edits: so this could cause many "errors" in a long document so that I thought to put here a specific question where I ask if there is some command to put into the preamble which do this automatically. So could someone help me, please?

Comment: you example is rather unnatural as tex can not break `.........`  it will break at word spaces (which you always have before inline math) or at `+` or `=` within the math.

Comment: If you put the formula into an mbox, then it won't be broken across lines.

Comment: What is the actual content of the unbroken long line?  A row of periods will never break on its own, so trying to guess how to help you is difficult.  If your line really is an unbroken row of periods, have a look at one of these previous questions: [Wrapping long lines that contain no spaces](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/6171) or [How to get long \texttt sections to break](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/299)

Comment: @DavidCarlisle Sorry but I do not understand exactly what you want mean: it seems you are saying to me that there is not a text with so consecutive types, right? So, I can say you that the points I inserted wanted represent a possibile text as "With the equation eq. \eqref{} we saw that but this is not really sure now and so we hat to use the equation $$ which is more usefull", that's all.

Comment: but it is impossible to guess what you want here, you should have a space before inline math and it will linebreak at the space if needed. What is your actual question? A real document should not have `\noindent`  or `\vspace` or `..............`  and all the issues with this example are just about those things, not about the math,

Comment: to get a numbrered equation you can reference use `\begin{equation} x=y \label{abc}\end{equation}` ....  see `\eqref{abc}`

Comment: @DavidCarlisle I edit the code putting a more precise example. Anyway you are saying that I can put the command \begin{equation}\end{eqution} without put the equation at the center?

Comment: Thank you for the improved example.  It seems that you need the spacing controls to be loosened.  To do this globally, you can put `\sloppy` in the preamble.  But this may also affect paragraphs that were acceptable before, and make them not as good looking.  To limit the effect to just one paragraph, put `\begin{sloppypar}` at the beginning of the paragraph (before `\noindent` if that is present), and `\end{sloppypar}` at the end.  Then the line breaking will be automatic.

Comment: @barbarabeeton Hi, thanks for your suggest. I tried both the solution you proposed but nothing work: I hat to add any package to my code?

Comment: This answer: https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/393686 confirms my belief that `sloppypar` is a feature of basic LaTeX.  But the answer also gives some examples that may help you understand it better.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are probably looking for something like this where the `{}` prevents line breaking in the math

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{parskip}
\begin{document}
    
    This is an example of unbreaked line.

    
    By the equation above we aruge that the following equiation (by Euler) $e^{i\pi}+1=0$ which is usefull.


    This is an example of \textbf{manually} breaked line

  
    By the equation above we argue that the following equation (by Euler)
    $e^{i\pi}+1=0$ which is useful.
    
    By the equation above we argue that the following equation (by Euler)
    ${e^{i\pi}+1=0}$ which is useful.
\end{document}
```

but see also

[Stop LaTeX from breaking an inline math equation](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/10850/stop-latex-from-breaking-an-inline-math-equation/94397#94397)